# Component is not populating by itself but rather with All components within my Header and Home Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

Have a pretty basic app through ReactJS but having trouble with routing to a new page and can't figure out why. When I click on the box that should route me to the Quiz page, the contents on that page populate (just saying "hello") but everything else on the page stays the same. I thought it had to do with the exact path but even still, everything remains the same and doesnt just show what's within my Quiz Component. Any thoughts? Appreciate all the help!

APP.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Components/Home/Home"
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header"
import Modal from "./Components/Modal/Modal"
import Quiz from "./Components/Quiz/Quiz"
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions: this.props.questions,
            show: false,
            
        };
    }
    // Function that opens/closes Modal
    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <Header />
                    {/* Input button for Modal */}
                    <input
                        className='open-modal-btn'
                        type='button'
                        onClick={this.showModal}
                        value=' Show Modal'
                    />

                    <Modal show={this.state.show} onClose={this.showModal}>
                        This message is from Modal
                    </Modal>
                </header>
                <Home />

                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path='/quiz'
                            render={() => {
                                return (
                                    <Quiz  />
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Home.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { username: '' };
    }
    // Updates the name of the User input Box
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <label htmlFor='Username'> Username: </label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='username'
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </form>
                    <div className='Allboxes'>
                        <div className='boxOne'>
                            <b> Name: </b> {this.state.username} <br />
                            <b> From: </b> Boston, MA <br />
                            <b> Interests: </b>Long walks on the beach, Golden Girls <br />
                        </div>
                        <div className='boxTwo'>
                            <b> Name: </b> {this.state.username} <br />
                            <b> From: </b> Dallas, TX <br />
                            <b> Interests: </b>Opera, Dank Memes <br />
                        </div>
                        <div className='boxThree'>
                            <b> Name: </b> {this.state.username} <br />
                            <b> From: </b> Long Beach, CA <br />
                            <b> Interests: </b>Shredding the Gnar, playing with yoyo's <br />
                        </div>
                        <Link to='/quiz'>
                            <div className='boxFour'>
                                <b> Name: </b> {this.state.username} <br />
                                <b> From: </b> Chicago, IL <br />
                                <b> Interests: </b>Pokemon, More Pokemon, Daisies <br />
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

QUIZ.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Quiz extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Quiz;
```

HEADER.JS

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Who Wants to be a Tandem Millionaire </h1>
                <Link to='/'> Home </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

MODAL.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Modal.css';

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    // Function that closes the Modal Button
    onClose = (e) => {
        this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose(e);
    };
    render() {
        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className='backdropStyle'>
                <div className='modalStyle'>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <div className='footerStyle'>
                        <button
                            className='close-modal-btn'
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                this.onClose(e);
                            }}>
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using react-router with custom history or browserHistory?

Comment: @Shyam I am not using either but should I be? I don't believe I have in the past either

Comment: So you have wrapped your routes / Switch with BrowserRouter, right?

Comment: @Shyam Whenever I do wrap my routes/switches with BrowserRouter, nothing then populates from the Quiz component and the only thing that changes is the URL with the ending "/quiz"

Comment: can you please create this in codesandbox or github link and share?

Comment: would like to understand where are other routes

Comment: @Shyam the github is here - https://github.com/mpgasbarro/Tandem-Quiz 

Thank you again for the help!

Comment: I did clone it here. https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-lalande-f591f seems routing to quiz is working here.

Answer (score 0):

To make route work, you must wrap your app with Router

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

ref: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: appreciate the help here! I've tried this as well and still nothing changes when I click the linked component